# How to dynamically add bytes data to Exoplayer MediaSource to continue playing downloaded bytes

Tags: android, arrays, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I was able to play audio which is saved in local file by converting it into  byte array and load in ExoPlayer in Android.

I wanted to know if there is any way to load streaming bytes of a large audio file into ExoPlayer as it downloads. I am downloading the large audio file from an external server. I don't want to wait for the audio to download completely and load the byte array.

Would help a lot if you have any ideas and suggestions or even point me in the right direction.

Comment: see `com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource`

Comment: Hi pskink, Would you can give me an example to how to add a bytes to a already initialized DataSource ?

Comment: did you see the sources of classes implementing `DataSource` interface? they sit in `com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream` folder

Comment: @pskink What can be done with the upstream datasource to play video?

Comment: @SaravanaKumarChinnaraj have you manage to figure it out?